# GCP Cloud Storage - Bucket Permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Accidentally I deleted a project owner from Bucket(Cloud storage) permissions.
So I can not do any operation like delete.

Any solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this an independent project or part of an organization? You might need to open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to recreate your issue using below steps.

In Case of account:

1. Removed my account(owner) from IAM Cloud Console
2. IAM & Admin page click ***+ADD***
3. New Principal and type/readd your old account
4. Select Role: 
   Basic > ***Owner*** or 
   Cloud Storage > ***Storage Admin***

You can add both by ***+ADD ANOTHER ROLE*** 
5. Save

In Case of Service Account:

Service account will remain up to 30 days.

1. Removed my service account(Storage Admin) from IAM Cloud Console
2. Under IAM & Admin I can still see my Service Account
3. IAM & Admin page click ***+ADD***
4. Add the deleted Service Account
5. Select Role > Cloud Storage > ***Storage Admin***
6. Save

Just make sure you have enough Access to configure IAM.

See below other docs for reference:

- [Manage access to projects, folders, and organizations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?hl=en)
- [Creating and managing custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles?hl=en)
- [Manage access to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/manage-access-service-accounts?hl=en)
- [Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en)